# Issue with call center simulation handling agent transitions

Tags: ruby

I am developing a program for a virtual call center. It has the following scenario:
­

- callers line up into the call center queue randomly at a certain
  rate, e.g. 100 calls / hour ­
- a fixed number of Agents (e.g. 50)
  serves the callers in the queue ­
- the length of each call varies randomly from 2 to 20 minutes ­
- after each time step, calculate:
- the approximate average current waiting 
  time -> the average time it takes for a 
  caller, from the time they call until transferred to an agent
- the average current serve time -> average 
  time between when a caller is transferred until the next caller is 
  transferred

I've noticed that the available number of agents always return to the original 50 after 25~ iterations even though the number of callers in the queue are getting higher. I think I must not be handling the agent transitioning from the busy queue to available queue correctly:

```
class Agent
  attr_accessor :serve_time, :time_limit
  @@total_time = 0
  @@number_of_callers = 0

  def initialize
    @serve_time = 0
    @time_limit = 0
  end

  def generate_time_limit
    @time_limit = rand(2.0..20.0)
  end

  def time_limit_reached?
    @serve_time >= @time_limit
  end

  def self.add_serve_time(time)
    @@total_time += time
    @@number_of_callers += 1
    self.avg_serve_time
  end

  def self.avg_serve_time
    return 'unknown' if @@number_of_callers == 0
    @@total_time / @@number_of_callers.to_f
  end
end

class Caller
  attr_accessor :wait_time
  @@total_time = 0
  @@number_of_callers = 0

  def initialize
    @wait_time = 0
  end

  def self.add_wait_time(time)
    @@total_time += time
    @@number_of_callers += 1
    self.avg_wait_time
  end

  def self.avg_wait_time
    return 'unknown' if @@number_of_callers == 0
    @@total_time / @@number_of_callers.to_f
  end
end

caller_queue = []
free_agent_queue = []
busy_agent_queue = []

#initiate agents
free_agent_queue = Array.new(50){Agent.new}

# Start the queue
100.times do |t|
  caller_queue.push(Caller.new)
  print "#{t}) queued callers #{caller_queue.size}, available agents #{free_agent_queue.size}, "
  caller_queue.each { |c| c.wait_time += 1 }
  # if there is avail agent and a caller in the queue, take the last 
  # caller in the queue out, take the last avail agent out and put that 
  # agent in the busy agent queue.
  if free_agent_queue.any? && caller_queue.any?
    busy_agent_queue.push(free_agent_queue.pop)
    busy_agent_queue.last.generate_time_limit
    busy_agent_queue.each { |b| b.serve_time += 1}
    Caller.add_wait_time(caller_queue.pop.wait_time)
  end
  print "avg wait time #{Caller.avg_wait_time}, "
  # any agents who's call time is up, take them out of the busy queue 
  # and back into the avail agent queue
  busy_agent_queue.reject!{ |a|
    if a.time_limit_reached?
      Agent.add_serve_time(a.serve_time)
      free_agent_queue.push(a)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  }
  puts "avg serve time #{Agent.avg_serve_time}"
end
```

And here is a typical output:
[image]

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with the way my code is written to handle the agents or achieve the scenarios listed?
I think the avg serving time might also have a problem that is related to this, since the counts seem way too high. Should I be using the class methods/variables the way that I am?

I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: You say that callers arrive randomly but you do not specify the arrival distribution. In fact, you seem to have 100 callers lined up at the door when processing begins, and those 100 are not followed by any more arrivals. Instead, you need need to simulate arrivals while servicing is being done. A common assumption is that arrivals constitute a *Poisson process*.  Briefly, this means that if the average time between arrivals is (say) 5 minutes, at any given point in time the average time until the next arrival occurs is 5 minutes, regardless of when the previous arrival occurred.

Comment: If you are prepared to use an exponential distribution for modelling service times (rather than a uniform distribution), as well as inter-arrival times, you wouldn't have to simulate; you could use a "M/M/s" queuing model to directly compute measures of interest, such as mean waiting time (even the waiting time distribution). See, for example, [this article](http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Queuing/MMs-Queuing-System.html). which presents the formulas and provides an on-line calculator.